# cURL API integration with dynamic data and header authentication

Tags: php, post, authorization, php-curl

I am working on auto sync between two systems. We have the database in one system and we are using another system for marketing. I am able to pull complete data from the database system. But when I am inserting the data to the marketing tool, it says invalid body request.

in the documentation, these are the details:

1)-**url**-:

`https://api.customdomain/recipients`

2)-**request body:**

```
    [
      {
        "email": "jones@example.com",
        "last_name": "Jones",
      }

]
```

3)-**auth-headers**:

authorization is done through the header.

```
Authorization: Bearer *API key goes here*;
```

This is the code I tried. **I should able to place data dynamically**.

```
$fields = array(
            'email' => "jam22@example.com",
            'last_name' => "test40"
            );
            
$methd="POST";
$url="https://api.customdomain/recipients";
$data=http_build_query($fields);
$rep= CallAPI($methd, $url, $fields);

echo $rep;

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

$headr=array(
    "authorization: Bearer *API key here*",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  );
  $ver="CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1";

    // Optional Authentication:
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
   // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,$ver);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: In the CallAPI function, i tried with $data which is `$data=http_build_query($fields);
$rep= CallAPI($methd, $url, $data);` 
still not working

Comment: I got it. The format of the body which Marketing tool receives is different from this array method. I modified the array to a string. Now it is working perfect

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The format of the body which Marketing tool receives is different from this array method. I modified the array to a string. Now it is working perfectly.

This is enough from CURL

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.custom");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//Setting post data as xml
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("authorization: API key"));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print($result);
```